# How to find an inflection point in a C# array or list?

Tags: c#, arrays, point

Using an array of stock prices how do I find all of the inflection points (indices of the array corresponding to the points where the slope reverses, ie local minimum and maximum values).

Based on math, I can use a second derivative but not sure how to do this in C#, and if there is a way to smooth out the data first to avoid noise.
For example if I have the following array of numbers:

```
1, 2, 3, 4.5, 5, 4.8, 5.2, 4.6, 4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1
```

I would like to find the following indices (starting from a zero index array): `4, 5, 6`. Also would like to know which indices are local Max and which are min.

Comment: Shouldn't you also want 9 and 11? I'd just have a bool value stating if you are going up or down, and store the values when it changes.

Answer (score 2):

**Given**

```
public static IEnumerable<double> GetStuff(double[] source)
{
   var polarity = true;

   for (var i = 1; i < source.Length; i++)
      if (polarity ? source[i] < source[i-1] : source[i] > source[i-1])
      {
         polarity = !polarity;
         yield return i - 1;
      }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var asd = new [] {1, 2, 3, 4.5, 5, 4.8, 5.2, 4.6, 4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1};

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",GetStuff(asd)));
```

**Output**

```
4,5,6,9,11
```

Comment: So from the output how do I know which indices are maximum values and which ones are minimum values? 
I kind of want to make a simple moving average line out of the array (as if the array were stock prices in time intervals), to find the inflection points on the smoothed out moving average. 
Is there a better way to say if there is a inflection point that there be a cutoff amount between nearby values such that if the nearby values are too close it should not count as a true inflection (rather these would be stock prices fluctuating up and down before the next trend.

Comment: I want to discourage you from updating your answer because (1) at this point it is obvious that the only actual problem here is that OP is just too lazy to type out any code, and (2) the additional inquiries are getting out of scope.

Comment: I liked the fact that you used a ternary operator as the `if` condition (I've never seen that or even thought of that) and the smart use of `yield`.

Comment: This literally saved my day. Thanks @TheGeneral. My curves were such that only one inflection points was expected but even then I checked and my checks all resulted in one index. Further, I needed more processing for each side so I took List<DataSet> loSets = dataSets.Take(idx + 1) and List<DataSet> hiSets = dataSets.Skip(idx) where idx was the hump index. I ran dozens of tests and quite a bit of debug and it worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second derivative. With discrete data, an inflection point is when consecutive non-zero differences have opposite signs. If the difference goes from positive to negative, it's a local max. If it goes from negative to positive, it's a local min.

Loop through the data, keeping track of the direction of the previous pair and output the indices, with a boolean flag indicating a max (true) or min (false):

```
public IDictionary<int,bool> FindMaxMin(IEnumerable<double> values)
{
   var prevDiff = 0;
   var result = new Dictionary<int,bool>()

   for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++) 
   {
      double newDiff = values[i] - values[i-1] 
      if (newDiff > 0 && prevDiff < 0)   // local min
      {
         result.Add(i, false);    
      }
      if (newDiff < 0 && prevDiff > 0)  // local max
      {
         result.Add(i, true);
      }
      if (newDiff != 0)     // keep track of the last non-zero diff
      {
          prevDiff = newDiff;
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Obviously some of the logic could be consolidated and/or a different data structure used for the output, but use whatever structure makes sense and whatever logic you can clearly understand after going a day without looking at it.

Comment: Just for the sake of it, I would make the second condition an `else if`.